# Mod_rewrite trouble: Want to direct from ?= to a flat link, nothing seems to work

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site that currently serves results as `example.com/index.php?show=foo`
and I'd like it to read `example.com/show/foo`.

My understanding is this would make them visible to search engine robots, and it seems a much simpler way to do this than to create a couple hundred html files...

I've tried the following .htaccess code:

`Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^show/(.*)$ index.php?show=$1 [NC,L]`

No dice.

Also tried this, which I found on another [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729776/htaccess-flat-links-url-shorten):

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]+)/?$ /index.php?show=$1 [L]

</IfModule>`

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Comment: If you don't get any errors that means that your `.htaccess` is ignored. Check `AllowOverride` directive in `httpd.conf`, make sure it's not `AllowOverride None`

Comment: Not getting any errors.  Can't find a httpd.conf, where would that be located?  Also, other .htaccess rules are being followed, like www.example.com being rewritten to example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `^([0-9A-Za-z]+)/?$` will try to match a request URI that only includes alphanumeric characters optionally trailed by a slash. Therefore the URI `show/foo` will not be matched because there are more characters at the end (ie, after the slash, where the expression expects to find the end of the string).

Try:

`RewriteRule ^show/([0-9A-Za-z]+)/?$ /index.php?show=$1 [L]`

Also, to capture aditional query parameters, you could do:

`RewriteRule ^show/([0-9A-Za-z]+)/?$ /index.php?show=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]`

This means a URL like `/show/page?id=1` rewrites to `/index.php?show=page&id=1`

Comment: Ok I got it to work, but now it's only working for single words, i.e. example.com/foo, but some of the queries are multiword and outputted as index.php?show=second+foo and that throws up a 404.

Comment: Ok figured it out, just had to add + after everything, so it becomes,  ([0-9A-Za-z+]+)

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this on sites that use 'seo-friendly' URLs.

In .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

Then on index.php:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=="home") {
    include ("home.php");
}
```

The .htaccess rule tells it to load index.php if the file or directory asked for was not found.  Then you just parse the request URI to decide what index.php should do.

You're on the right track, but your rule has issues.  `.*` is pretty all inclusive.  Start there and go more restrictive if needed.